# some rational function that I can't solve?

Tags: rational-functions

According to this rational function

$$ f(x) = \frac{x + \frac{3}{8}}{x+ \frac{2}{5}} $$

what is $f(1/4)$?

My choices: $\frac{35}{52}$, $1$, $\frac{52}{30}$, $\frac{20}{9}$, $\frac{9}{2}$

Comment: On such a basic problem, you need to show an attempt. Evaluating $f1/4)$ means to replace all occurrences of $x$ by $1/4$. Let's see you try it.

Comment: All the choices given are wrong.  Let us know what your answer is and we can then confirm it.

Comment: Books (or handouts) can have errors -- still, you need to show what _you_ tried -- that's expected on this site.

Comment: Hint: you need to evaluate the function at $x=1/4$. This means putting the value $1/4$ in the place of $x$, resulting in
$$ f \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) = 
\frac{ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{8}  }{  \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{5}}
$$
Now you only need to simplify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top:
$$\frac{2}{8}+\frac{3}{8}\ = \frac{5}{8}$$

bottom:
$$\frac{5}{20}+\frac{8}{20}\ = \frac{13}{20}$$

answer:
$$\frac{100}{104}$$

not sure where you're getting your options from but this is the correct answer without reducing

Comment: Thanks for proving the answers given to me by this ACT precalc practice test wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE!
$$f(x) = \frac{x + \frac{3}{8}}{x+ \frac{2}{5}}$$
Just put the value $x=1/4$
$$f(1/4)= \frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{8}}{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{5}}$$.

Simplify it and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply multiply numerator and denominator by $40$ to get
$$\frac{\frac14 + \frac{3}{8}}{\frac14+ \frac{2}{5}}=\frac{40\cdot\left(\frac14 + \frac{3}{8}\right)}{40\cdot\left(\frac14+ \frac{2}{5}\right)} 
=\frac{10+15}{10+16}.$$